# Stability analysis of a three-dimensional system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Study the stability of the equilibrium point $(y,q,z)=(0,0,0)$. (Hypothesis: $\nu,\theta,\zeta$ are positive.)

$$\begin{align}
\dot{y}&=y(1-\nu -\theta -y-z+\theta y-(\nu +\zeta)q)\\
\dot{q}&=(1+q)(\theta y-(\nu +\zeta)q)\\
\dot{z}&=\zeta q-\nu z+z(\theta y-(\nu +\zeta)q)
\end{align}$$

S started by finding the Jacobian matrix J and I have that it is

$$\begin{bmatrix}1-\nu-\theta-2y-z+2\theta y-(\nu+\zeta)q & -(\nu+\zeta)y & -y \\ \theta(1+q) & \theta y-\nu-2\nu q-\zeta-2\zeta q & 0 \\ \theta z & \zeta-\nu z-\zeta z & -\nu+\theta y-\nu q-\zeta q \end{bmatrix}$$
I found $J_{(0,0,0)}$ and I have that it equals

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1-\nu -\theta & 0 & 0 \\ \theta & -\nu -\zeta & 0 \\ 0 & \zeta & -\nu \end{bmatrix}$$

I found that my eigenvalues are

$$\begin{align}
\lambda_1 &= 1-\nu -\theta=1-(\nu+\theta) \\
\lambda_2 &= -\nu -\zeta=-(\nu+\zeta) \\
\lambda_3 &= -\nu 
\end{align}$$

By the hypothesis, we can tell that $\lambda_2<0$ and $\lambda_3<0$. So they both have negative real parts (I think that's correct to say). If $\lambda_1<0$ then the equilibrium would be stable but I cannot tell whether it would be positive or negative from the information I have.

My textbook has a chapter on analyzing the stability but it only involves 2-dimensional. I found this [website](http://home.comcast.net/~sharov/PopEcol/lec9/equilib.html), but the information seems to only be about 2-dimensional systems.